# How do I stop Blender 2.8 from creating extra faces when I just want to stretch pre-existing faces?

Tags: modeling, faces

I'm new to blender so I'm sorry if this is a noob question. Here is an example of what I want to happen when I click and drag the face along the Y axis (represented by the green arrow):

From this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

However, two extra faces appear when I try to drag along the y-axis:

[image]

Here's the face I'm stretching along the Y-axis:

[image]

Any help at all on this would be greatly appreciated. If you need more information I'd be happy to give it to you. Thank you all!

Comment: so you must have overlapping vertices... before pulling the edges, select all (A) and alt M > Merge By Distance to make sure you've deleted those vertices (check the Operator box on the bottom left of the 3D View to play with the threshold)

Comment: HAHA It worked! You're a genius. Thank you so much, this has helped a lot!

Comment: since this solved the issue, maybe @moonboots can put that into an answer that OP can accept and close the question? OP: check [tour] to understand what I mean too, instead of adding [SOLVED] to the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have overlapping vertices. Before pulling the edges, select all (<kbd>A</kbd>) and <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge By Distance* to make sure you've deleted those vertices (check the *Operator* box on the bottom left of the 3D view to play with the threshold)